# How to open previous activity by clicking on the custom back button on UnityPlayerActivity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I need to add a unity game in one my android application. The functionality of the application is, There is a button in my android application. By clicking on the button it opens the UnityPlayerActivity (Unity native android code is exported via IDE used for unity game development). Now game is successfully being played from my application. On the home page, game contains a back button. Click action of that back button is handled on the android code where I have mentioned

```
unityPlayer.currentActivity.finish()
```

When I called above, my application reinitializes. I don't know why is this happening and why am I unable to back from UnityPlayerActivity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of investigation, I found inside the UnityPlayer following line kill the complete process.

```
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```

This is mentioned inside a method named **kill()**. For solving my problem I made a base class of UnityPlayer and override kill() method by mentioning nothing inside the body of the same. Now my problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this code to go back instead.

```
public void goBack() {
 Runnable action = new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
             onBackPressed();             
     }
 };
 runOnUiThread(action);}
```